# Similiar functions to traverse a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I have got a binary tree

```
     public class Node
    {
            int value;
            Node left;
            Node right;

            public Node getLeft() {
                return left;
            }

        public Node getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

And in main I have got a function to traverse it.
For tree

```
    5
   / \
  3   7
 / \
1   2
```

First one creates a queue of nodes with breadth first traversal(5,3,7,1,2).
Second one returns value of a node for eg. 7 for number 2 or 2 for number 4.

```
    private void queueOfTreaversed() {
        LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        if (root != null)
            queue.add(root);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node temp = queue.removeFirst();
            if (temp.getLeft() != null && temp.getRight() != null) {
                traversed.add(temp);    //there is a difference
                queue.add(temp.getLeft());
                queue.add(temp.getRight());
            }
        }
    }

    public int getValue(int n) {
        LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        if (root != null)
            queue.add(root);

        while (!queue.isEmpty() && n>0) {
            Node temp = queue.removeFirst();
            if (temp.getLeft() != null && temp.getRight() != null) {
                queue.add(temp.getLeft());
                queue.add(temp.getRight());
            }
        }
        return queue.peekFirst().getValue();  //there is a difference
    }
```

And I have got duplication of code that I do not how to get rid off.
I use *traversed* in meantime and pop elements from this queue so elements will not be in this order and *traversed* cannot be used. Could anyone give any hint?

Comment: Where is the variable "traversed" in the first method initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have got the traversed nodes in `traversed`, your `getValue(int n)` function can actually index into `traversed` to get the value you want. In your `getValue(int n)` function, just use code like this:

```
if (n < traversed.size()) {
    return traversed.get(n).getValue();
}
throw new Exception("Element not existed");
```

To be able to use `traversed`, just return it in your `queueOfTreaversed` function.

Comment: I have forgot to tell that I use **traversed** in meantime and pop elements from this queue so elements will not be in this order and **traversed** cannot be used

Comment: @Mateusz Still, same thing. Since in your `queueOfTraversed()` function you've already traversed the entire tree. Just create a list containing all the nodes in this function and return it, which can be furthered used in your `getValue()` function. You don't have to particularly use `traversed`.

Comment: @Mateusz It looks to me that your `queueOfTraversed()` does nothing else than creating a queue containing all the nodes in breadth first order. This queue can be returned or duplicated in this function and then be used in `getValue()` function.